# Recommendation topic - Numerical Analysis and computational

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, big-list, reference-works

I'm having a course about *'Numerical Analysis and computational'* in my master's. The course is about :

- Systems of Linear Equations: direct methods (LU factorization and Cholesky decomposition), iterative methods (Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel).
- Eigenvalues: localization, power method and deflation, Householder triangularization, tridiagonal matrices, SVD.
- QR factorization and least squares. Conditioning.

I need to do a report about some topic of the content, specifically a method solving a system of equations involving specific matrices (hilbert, cholesky , etc.. )(Example: Cholesky's Method - Resolving Normal Equation Systems)

**My question is** : Can someone recommend me a topic to talk about. For example some physics problems that involve this type of matter?

Something that has material enough to do a report and so I get some matlab work on it.

Comment: Look into optimization. Specifically, linear programming. Very useful for efficient optimization